# What are the maximum and minimum values of $4x + y^2$ subject to $2x^2 + y^2 = 4$?

Tags: calculus, optimization, maxima-minima, qcqp

$$ 2x^2 + y^2 = 4 $$
$$ Y = \sqrt{4-2x^2} $$

$$4x + y =  2x^2 +  \sqrt{4-2x^2}$$
Find the derivative of $$ 2x^2 +  \sqrt{4-2x^2} $$  set as = 0
$$X^2 = 64/33$$
$$ F(64/33) = 34\sqrt{33}/33 $$

How to solve it the right way?

Comment: There is a mismatch between question title and body: Is  $4x + y^2$ or $4x+y$ the expression whose extremal values you want?

Comment: 4x + y^2, sorry

Answer (score 3):

you will get $$4x+y^2=4x+4-2x^2$$

Answer (score 1):

Note that $y^2=-2x^2+4$

When performing substitution of $4x+y^2 \rightarrow 4x-2x^2+4$

Finding the vertex (maxima):

$$-2x^2+4x+4=-2(x^2-2x)+4=-2[(x-1)^2-1]+4=-2(x-1)^2+6$$

Which presents the relative(and only) maxima.

Note that there is no relative minima, as the parabola goes downwards.

Comment: Max is 6. And min is -4\sqrt{2}

Comment: $x^2\le2$ gives a bound for the value of $x$

Comment: Where does x^2 <= 2 come from ?

Comment: Where do you see that?

Comment: @CY Aries comment..

Answer (score 0):

[image]
I hope the image explains it all.

[image]

Comment: image only answers are frowned upon.

Comment: But mathjax takes a lot of time

Comment: Which means you do not want to put in effort.

Comment: I am doing my best. I think that if the image answer can be understood by the person who asks the question, then what is the need for Mathjax? Why do I need to give more time for something which can be done easily in a short time? I think the image answers fulfil the purpose th answers are meant for.

Comment: The answer is max = 6. Min = -4\sqrt{2}

Comment: @hely123 I am sorry I made a mistake. I have edited the solution. I hope you understand it

Comment: Please convert your answer to MathJax.

Comment: What is the extreme value of x that is $\sqrt 2$ isn't the extreme value is 1?